# What is a "turkey walk"?

Tags: expressions, american-english

I once read that a "turkey walk" was going to be held on a Sunday at 8.00 a.m. in a small town in New England.

I tried to find it in dictionaries and I also googled the expression, but got no results.

Can anyone explain what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Turkey trot" is traditionally a short run held on the morning of Thanksgiving - the fourth Thursday in November in the USA, and a day when turkey is on the menu in almost every household in remembrance of the "first thanksgiving" when the Pilgrims, according to tradition, ate turkey in a feast to celebrate that they had survived for a year in the new colonies.

According to [this event listing](http://www.boston.com/travel/blog/2012/11/new_england_tur.html) not all these events are "trots" (which are runs), nor are they all on the Thursday.

It is therefore most likely that this was a walk "close to the Thanksgiving holiday", probably in the thanksgiving "spirit" (meaning decorations included cornucopias, Pilgrims's hats, squash and pumpkins, corn eaves, and lots of turkeys).

Comment: I wouldn't bat an eye at a Turkey Trot held any time over Thanksgiving weekend (as opposed to just on Thursday).

Comment: @J.R. yes it seems that "close to Thanksgiving" qualifies. When you look at that link I gave in the answer, it's got dates (for 2014) ranging from Nov 17 through 25 - that doesn't even go as far as Thanksgiving. Other sites have other dates. Clearly the date range is wider than I had realized.

Comment: Reading your answer today, I'm amazed to see how you managed to write such a long sentence. It would be difficult for me.

Comment: @Centaurus- it does go on a bit now that I re-read it!

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess that a "turkey walk" is a toned-down version of a "turkey trot", which is a short (usually 5 kilometers) running race held on the Thanksgiving holiday in the United States.

chris

Comment: The odd thing is that this walk was to be held on a Sunday. "Turkey trots" are traditionally (only) held on the fourth Thursday of November... they are so named because Thanksgiving is a day when turkey is traditionally served, making it known as "turkey day" in some circles. Since it's often associated with excessive eating and drinking, starting the day with a short run is considered an antidote to the inevitable "calorie-induced coma" that follows.

Comment: @Floris, It was in November and I'm not really sure it was to be held on a Sunday.

Comment: @Centaurus - OK see my answer. It need not have been on a Thursday, but being in November was definitely a good sign...